# In the Windows Store I have "Unknown" error, with no further details?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've recently updated my app Essential Video Recorder.  It handles things like video size adjusts with windows size, and there is now the ability to access more camera settings.

All well and good, but, the first release of it was making the health report look funky.  One was simple, I hadn't carried over my trapping, so pushed out .1 with better trapping and recovery; however, I now have an error in the health report, that just says "Unknown".  Don't have a clue about how I should deal with it.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I should address this?

Thanks, John.

Comment: You can try to file a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account to see if they could help.

Comment: @Annievia-MSFT or they can just simply find who has this error and fix the issue that prevents a useful message? Like 30% of errors on one of my apps are just "Unknown". Very useful information indeed.

Comment: I am not sure if they can or not. Did you file the support ticket? What did they say? @John Leone

Comment: I did enter a support ticket, they thought it might have something to do with the fact they had recently upgraded the Dashboard.  However, I put a new version up that trapped the known error, and the "Unknown" error disappeared.  Whatever it was it is now gone.  Am not sure if it was the Dashboard or my code that got resolved.